# Java SE app wide exception tracking

Tags: java, exception

I want to be able to track all exceptions that occur in an app that i am developing then send it to a remote server where it can be analyzed. I need something that has ability to store exceptions offline and sync when online.

Comment: IMHO, you should use `Logger` and associated `.log` files.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend the ELK stack to collect, store and show your logs.
FileBeat does syncing to LogStash automatically.

It is free and very reliable.

I also recommend using slf4j and logback for logging with markers and MDC for your special purposes.